# Iron Router Meteor 1.2, this.request.body is empty

Tags: post, meteor, iron-router

Meteor 1.2

```
Router.route('/upload', {
  where: 'server',
  action: function(){
    console.log(this.request.body);
    this.response.end(JSON.stringify(this.request.body));
  }
});
```

I am using the lines mentioned in earlier [issues](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1190).

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    }));
}
```

Still the response is {}. Did this break with meteor 1.2? What is the solution now?

Answer (score 1):

// this is my route

```
Router.map(function(){
    this.route('/posted',{where:'server'})
    .post(function(){
        console.log(this.request.body);
        this.response.end('post request\n');
    });
});
```

// this is my form

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/posted">
    <input name="test" value="blah"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

// this is my reply on server's console

```
//I20151026-12:27:21.421(-6)? { test: 'blah' }
```

hope this helps

Comment: this just saved me alot of time. This snippet is very important and its funny that it was very difficult to find. Thank you!